# app explosion with conflicting sql primary key

Tags: android, exception, insert, sqlite

I have a table in a database where the _id column is the primary key.  If I try to do an insert into this table using an _id that already exists, my application crashes.  How can I do this?  Is there a specific kind of Exception I can eat?  I've tried SQLiteException to no avail.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are inserting the ID yourself, and not letting the database assign one for you? As for the type of exception, surely that will be outlined in the exception details?

Comment: I'm syncing data being pulled from a web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my problem.

I'm now using insertOrThrow and catching SQLiteExceptions.  Also, I was throwing another exception all the way to the top without catching it anywhere.  I am now catching and logging this.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the primary key needs to be unique -- a single value must reference a single row.

You can only do what you want by changing something -- either the database structure, so this column is no longer defined as a primary key (though think carefully before you do this -- any application written against the old schema will assume, when selecting based on the _id field, that a single id will yield a single row, and you will break that assumption, and very likely the application).  The other thing is to change the data to give it a new _id.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What I am doing here is syncing data being pulled from a web service.  Currently, the syncing is written such that a new row will never be pulled twice.  However, should something slip through the cracks, I don't want the application to crash on the user.  I understand what a primary key is and I would like a clean way to handle this exception.